# Adding a closure to a customButton in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert the following code in Obj-c to swift:

CustomButton.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^defaultAction)();
```

CustomButton.m

```
- (void)executeTargetActionBlock {
      if (self.defaultAction)
           self.defaultAction();
}

- (void) initialize {
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(executeTargetActionBlock) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

This initializeMethod is called in the init method of CustomButton.

Comment: It's worth pointing at that code like this can very easily create a retain cycle if `defaultAction` has a `strong` reference to the owner of the button instance (which seems likely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var defaultAction: (() -> Void)?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addTarget(self, action: "executeTargetActionBlock", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func executeTargetActionBlock() {
        if let action = defaultAction {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this more swifty you can abbreviate `UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside` to `.TouchUpInside` and make the conditional block execution a one-liner `defaultAction?()`